# retrieve access-token from devise auth response headers

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ionic-framework, devise, http-headers

I have a Rails api only app using the gem "devise_token_auth" for the user authentication, and a IONIC 2 client that I'm implementing from scratch, already got the user´s registration working, but the problem is the login, the rails app sends the "OK" response with the headers, but I´m having trouble to retrieve the access-token from the headers because the json is all nested in a strange way, and I didn´t override nothing, is the default devise token auth response.

Ionic service method:

```
 ` login(credentials) {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        let headers = new Headers();
        headers.append('Content-Type', 'application/json');

        this.http.post(apiUrl+'auth/sign_in', JSON.stringify(credentials), {headers: headers})
          .subscribe(res => {
            resolve(res.json());
            debugger;
          }, (err) => {
            console.log(err);
          });
    });
  }`
```

Already tried res.headers / res.headers.get('access-token'), but is too nested, it retrieves null or undefined that i´m afraid i´m missing something.

[debugger printscreen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WtfXv.png)

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Apparently I was sending the res as a json, so in the other component I wasn´t able to use the http methods. Using this methods of the http angular lib I was able to retrieve that with just: `res.headers.get('access-token')`

That I wasn´t confident because the response in the console looks more nested, but that did the trick. Now I am able to store the token and implement the login feature.